# Does powershell string manipulation adds junk character?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

When i am placing my $string variable contents into some text file, it adds some junk character it seems. For example i am writing an utility name in string and copy that string to file like follows.

```
$CodeCount+="ccount.exe"

$CodeCount | Out-file "C:\CodeCount.bat"
```

When i am executing this batch file , it fails by showing some junk character in front.[image]

Even i tried with trim() but still the same result.

How to avoid adding Junk character in front?

Comment: Try `Out-File -Encoding ASCII`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `out-file`, atleast, in the default form. Use `set-content`. Or explicitly set the encoding in `out-file` something like `out-file -encoding ascii`. Out-file by default uses utf16 ( ucs-2 actually) encoding which doesn't get treated as plain text in many applications ( including version control systems like Hg, Git ) and add the "funny" characters that you mention.

Note that the redirection `>` is same as out-file and will give you the same results.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the standard encoding used for `Out-file` is `Unicode` which adds some BOM values at the beginning of the file (you can see these values when you open your file with a hex editor). To avoid these bytes use `-encoding ASCII`:

```
$CodeCount | Out-file -encoding ascii "C:\CodeCount.bat"
```

Answer (score 2):

The default encoding of `Out-File` is Little Endian Unicode. `cmd.exe` doesn't work well with this encoding so just use `ASCII`:

`Out-File -Encoding ASCII`